# What are pros and cons of piezo Vs strain gauges bed leveling sensors?

Tags: bed-leveling

I'm designing a dual hotend carriage for a HEVO printer that will run in an enclosed heated chamber and I'm evaluating which bed leveling sensor I should use.

I [read](https://youtu.be/79r5D9nCQfM) that BLTouch and similar sensors stop working in a hot environment, and likewise, capacitive and inductive sensors are affected [significantly](https://youtu.be/il9bNWn66BY). Piezo and strain gauges (force-sensitive resistors) are my choices.

What are the differences in practice? Both related to the heated chamber (70+ °C) and in general at room temperature.